# How do I handle separate input focus states?

Tags: react-native

I have two different textInputs that I want to animate when they are in focus and/or have a value.

I cannot find an example anywhere where they have multiple TextInputs and style them separately when in focus.

In my current code both TextInput's gets focused.

How are you guys handling this?

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        isFocused: false,
    }

    isFocused = () => this.setState({isFocused: true});
    isBlur = () => this.setState({isFocused: false});

    render(){
        return(
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.LoginWrapper} behavior="padding">
                <View style={styles.LoginContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.LoginTitle}>Sign In</Text>
                    <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
                        <Text style={styles.Label}>Username or Email {this.state.isFocused ? 'focused' : 'unfocused'}</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            returnKeyType="next"
                            onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
                            keyboardType="email-address"
                            autoCapitalize="none"
                            autoCorrect={false}
                            onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({username})}
                            value={this.state.username}
                            onFocus={this.isFocused}
                            onBlur={this.isBlur}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
                        <Text style={styles.Label}>Password {this.state.isFocused ? 'focused' : 'unfocused'}</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            returnKeyType="go"
                            ref={(input) => this.passwordInput = input}
                            secureTextEntry
                            onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                            value={this.state.password}
                            onFocus={this.isFocused}
                            onBlur={this.isBlur}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.ForgotPasswordText}>Forgot your password?</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.dispatch(loginRequest(this.state.username, this.state.password))}>
                        <Text style={styles.LoginText}>SIGN IN</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.signupButton}>
                        <Text style={styles.signupButtonText}>Sign Up</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: why can't you call different onFocus functions for the TextInput ?

Comment: I feel like it is the wrong way of doing that, DRY kind of

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to fix it:

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        FocusedElement: null,
    }

    onFocus = (FocusedElement) => this.setState({ FocusedElement })
    onBlur = () => this.setState({ FocusedElement: null })

    render(){
        return(
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.LoginWrapper} behavior="padding">
                <View style={styles.LoginContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.LoginTitle}>Sign In</Text>
                    <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
                        <Text style={styles.Label}>Username or Email {this.state.FocusedElement === 'emailInput' ? 'focused' : 'unfocused'}</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            returnKeyType="next"
                            onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
                            keyboardType="email-address"
                            autoCapitalize="none"
                            autoCorrect={false}
                            onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({username})}
                            value={this.state.username}
                            onFocus={() => this.onFocus('emailInput')}
                            onBlur={this.isBlur}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.inputWrap}>
                        <Text style={styles.Label}>Password {this.state.FocusedElement === 'passwordInput' ? 'focused' : 'unfocused'}</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            returnKeyType="go"
                            ref={(input) => this.passwordInput = input}
                            secureTextEntry
                            onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                            value={this.state.password}
                            onFocus={() => this.onFocus('passwordInput')}
                            onBlur={this.isBlur}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.ForgotPasswordText}>Forgot your password?</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.dispatch(loginRequest(this.state.username, this.state.password))}>
                        <Text style={styles.LoginText}>SIGN IN</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.signupButton}>
                        <Text style={styles.signupButtonText}>Sign Up</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ended up splitting the textInputs to their own component files which solved my issue.